# Cant figure out what Error means and how to solve it

Tags: recursion, ocaml

Here is the **error code** I have:

```
Characters 2004-2008
Error: The type constructor list expects 1 argument(s),
but is here applied to 0 argument(s)
```

Here is the **Ocaml code** I have written:

```
let createHuffmanTree (s:string) = match s with
    | "" -> Empty    (*Return an empty huffman tree ifstring is empty*)
    | _ -> let rec ca (l: list) (a: huffman) = match l with (*ERROR SHOULD BE ON THIS LINE*)
        | [] -> a (*If list is [] return the huffman tree*)
        | x,_ -> fold_left (ca) l level(leaf(x),a) (*For all the ellement of the list create a level and corresponding leaf*)
        in ca listFreq(explode(s)) Empty (*Start with an empty tree*)
```

**Note:**

`explode` take a string return it as a list of char
ex:

```
# explode "Test";; 
- : char list = ['T'; 'e'; 's'; 't']
```

`listFreq` take the list from explode and return a pair of char * int being the char and the number of time it is found in the list return by explode
ex:

```
# listeFreq (explode "AABCAABADBACAAB");; 
- : (char * int) list = [('A', 8); ('B', 4); ('C', 2); ('D', 1)]
```

The Huffman Tree I am trying to create take a string (for exemple `"AAABBC"`)
and do this:

```
        level
|                   |
v                   v
leaf A            level
               |         |
               v         v
               leaf B    leaf C
```

The tree could also be `Empty`

**Question:**
I have no idea how to solve the error code. Could someone point out a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that instead of `(l: list)`, you should have something like `(l: 'a list)`.

Comment: oh... Now that you point it out it seems so stupid, let me check if this solve the problem XD